# a strange issue on rdkafka,can not exit from the script

Tags: php, apache-kafka

```
<?php
$conf = new \RdKafka\Conf();
        $conf->set('group.id', 'elk_consumedeijhelloworld'); 
        $rk = new \RdKafka\Consumer($conf);
echo 111;exit;
echo 222;
```

the terminal output just 111 and hang up (no response，no exit),
the progress is still there
why?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you hit this issue which was fixed in php-rdkafka 3.0.2: https://github.com/arnaud-lb/php-rdkafka/issues/115

Try upgrading to a newer version of php-rdkafka